# How can I build GridView on Design within UserControl?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have this:

```
<uc:MyCustomGridView runat="server">

</uc:MyCustomGridView>
```

This is an UserControl which is not only a GridView. It has some other controls, like a menu bar on top, and a title.

I would like to create a GridView inside my MyCustomGridView like this:

```
<uc:MyCustomGridView runat="server">
    <uc:MyCustomGridView.GridView>
        <Columns>
             <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Code" DataField="Code" />
             <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Description" DataField="Description" />
        </Columns>
    </uc:MyCustomGridView.GridView>
</uc:MyCustomGridView>
```

Is something like this possible? Is there any keyword that I should search for?

Answer (score 0):

I solved by reading the following tutorial:

http://www.tomot.de/en-us/article/2/asp.net/how-to-create-an-asp.net-control-that-behaves-as-a-template-container-to-nest-content-via-markup